# Expanding path variable in makefile using SED on Windows

Tags: regex, sed, cmd, makefile

On Windows machine, a makefile is taking path option and creating another file by appending this path value.

My problem is that path variable is not expanding correct in resultant file.

For example

```
$ make var=c:\test\kernel
```

by using below makefile code this $(var) value is being appending to output file

```
all:
      @sed -i '1 i\export PATH := $(var)' output.txt
```

Expected result

```
export PATH := c:\test\kernel
```

But instead I'm getting

```
export PATH := c:   estkernel
```

So, how I can fix this problem in makefile?

Comment: Looks like the `\t` in `c:\test\kernel` is interpreted as a tab, escape the backslashes (with another one)

Comment: What are you running that provides sed, make, and a shell? cygwin, mingw, ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I strongly urge you to always use forward slashes in paths even on Windows, especially when working with make.  There are very few programs on Windows that won't work with forward-slashes (mainly old-school CMD commands etc.) and using backslashes in tools which have their provenance in UNIX will always be an uncomfortable fit.

For your situation you can do something like this:

```
all:
        @sed -i '1 i\export PATH := $(subst \,\\,$(var))' output.txt
```

to convert your backslashes to escaped backslashes.